# Compare two columns and return another cell value in the matched row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vlookup

Thanks everyone!

I have 2 sheets in the same workbook. I want cell A2 of Sheet1 to have a formula that looks at the cell on the left (B2, "Company Name") and then searches for a match in Sheet2 column A (the entire column, "Company Name"). If there is a match, then I want Sheet1 cell A2 to populate with the value to the right of the matched cell (Sheet2, column B).

Sheet1 looks like:

```
 [Account ID]---[Account Name]
 [          ]---[Company 1   ]
 [          ]---[Company 2   ]
 [          ]---[Company 3   ]
```

Sheet2 looks like:

```
 [Account Name]---[Account ID]
 [Company 3   ]---[123456    ]
 [Company 1   ]---[736936    ]
 [Company 2   ]---[192563    ]
```

What is the best way of going about this. Let me know if more explanation is needed! Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Just to practice index/match, `=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(B1,A:A,0))` should also work. Edit: uh, I am only using 1 sheet.

Comment: @findwindow - (Don't forget the sheet references)

Comment: Batman, too lazy, just used 1 sheet =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfect for a [`Vlookup()`](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel-tips/how-to-use-excels-vlookup-function) formula.  In your Sheet1, Cell A2, use this formula `=Vlookup(B2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3,2,False)`.

Adjust the ranges as necessary

Comment: I take the day off and look other people answer the questions. Note to self take more days off.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Now I have a follow up... What if #N/A is returned, but I then want it too look for a match in Sheet1 column C, with Sheet2 column C?